# How can I put a bomb only once until it explodes in the physics arcade pool?

Tags: phaser-framework

I want to put only one bomb every x second

```
Bomb extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Group {
constructor(physicsWorld, scene) {
    super(physicsWorld, scene)
}

newBomb(x, y){

    let bomb = this.create(x, y, 'bomb')

    if(bomb){
        bomb.setActive(true)
        bomb.setVisible(true)
        bomb.setImmovable(true)
        bomb.setOrigin(0)

        setTimeout(()=> {
          bomb.disableBody(true, true)
          console.log('BOOM!')
        }, 3000)
    }
}
```

the publication tells me that I have to write more otherwise I will not be able to publish this message -.- the only thing I want is to put a bomb every x minutes until it explodes

Comment: did my answer solve your question, or do you need some more help?

Answer (score 0):

Without more code / information, I just can guess.

Since it seems that your are creating a new Bomb each time the function `newBomb` is called. I would just go with the function `destroy`, this should remove the Object from the scene.

I would write something like this:

```js
class SimpleLevel extends Phaser.Scene {
    bombs;
    constructor() {
        super("SimpleLevel");
    }

    create() {
        // ... here comes the usual init and load code ...
        this.bombs = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
        this.addNewBomb(100, 100); // some Coordinates
    }

    addNewBomb(x, y) {
        let bomb = this.physics.add.image(x, y, "bomb");
        this.bombs.add(bomb);
        setTimeout(() => bomb.destroy(), 3000);
    }

    update(time, delta) {
        if (this.bombs.getLength() == 0) // when the group is empty create new bomb
            this.addNewBomb(100, 100); // some Coordinates
    }
}
```

details here https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite#destroy
Ofcourse you could hide the bombs and respawn them, but following the advice of this post [best way to destroy an object](https://phaser.discourse.group/t/best-way-to-destroy-a-object/3209) I would recomend first to try this *easy* approach.